# Get entity name/label from wikidata in python

Tags: python, sparql, mediawiki, wikidata, mediawiki-api

I have some SPARQL queries to run on wikidata in python and I need to get the name/label of the entity returned instead of URI. For example, given the python snippet below:

```
from qwikidata.sparql  import return_sparql_query_results

query_string = """
        select ?ent where { ?ent wdt:P31 wd:Q2637056 . ?ent wdt:P2244 ?obj } ORDER BY DESC(?obj)LIMIT 5 
        """

res = return_sparql_query_results(query_string)
for row in res["results"]["bindings"]:
   print(row["ent"]["value"])
```

The queries in the original form return URIs, but I need to get the entity label/name. How can I do that in python?

The current output of the query:

```
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q841796
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q780047
```

NOTE: I don't have real access to the queries, therefore I can't rewrite the queries.

Comment: If you can't rewrite the queries, how should it be possible to get the labels? I mean, ok you could run another SPARQL query - but does this make sense?

Comment: @UninformedUser, are there other ways I can use to retrieve the labels without rewriting the SPARQL query as I don't have access to it?

Comment: Well, indeed you have to query Wikidata somehow. either by running another SPARQL query to get the label for each URI, or you do some other non-SPARQL request like `https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q841796.json` which return the JSON data which in fact contains an entry for the labels

Answer (score 0):

My comment was too long so i am posting an answer.
You'll need to rewrite the queries. Please find below an example how to get labels without using the label service.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel 
WHERE 
{
  # instance of country
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.
  OPTIONAL {
     ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel filter (lang(?countryLabel) = "en").
   }
} 
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%23%20instance%20of%20country%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FcountryLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel)

Adapted for your Soyuz-T  example:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT ?ent ?entLabel
WHERE 
{ 
  # instance of Soyuz-T https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2637056
  ?ent wdt:P31 wd:Q2637056 . 
  # https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2244 periapsis
  ?ent wdt:P2244 ?obj 
  OPTIONAL {
     ?ent rdfs:label ?entLabel filter (lang(?entLabel) = "en").
  }     
} ORDER BY DESC(?obj)LIMIT 5
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fent%20%3FentLabel%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%20%0A%20%20%23%20instance%20of%20Soyuz-T%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FQ2637056%0A%20%20%3Fent%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ2637056%20.%20%0A%20%20%23%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FProperty%3AP2244%20periapsis%0A%20%20%3Fent%20wdt%3AP2244%20%3Fobj%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fent%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FentLabel%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FentLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fobj%29LIMIT%205%20)

Result:

```
ent         entLabel
wd:Q841796  Soyuz T-15
wd:Q780047  Soyuz T-8
```